# mobile back button not working in phonegap project?

Tags: eclipse, cordova

When i click on a link this will redirect me to another page in my app.

But after that when i am clicking on the mobile's back button it is not redirect me to previous page.

Ca anyone have answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually device's back button click is also an event in PhoneGap. You can define the beckbutton event as a function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonClick, false);
        }

        function backButtonClick() {
            //Do something here on backbutton click or go back to last page.
            window.history.back()
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Its a sample, now tweak your page as you wanted.
Always write the backbutton event on deviceready!